# Parsing an IPv4 value using CASE statement

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to convert this to using a CASE statement instead of the IF statement but I get "incorrect syntax near Set".

Its on the first SET:

```
WHEN 1 THEN 
   SET @firstOctet = CAST( SUBSTRING( @WorkingNullRouteIP, 1, @lastOctet - 1 ) )


     DECLARE @lastOctet              int,
             @octetCount             int,
             @firstOctet             int = -1,
             @secondOctet            int = -1,
             @thirdOctet             int = -1,
             @fourthOctet            int = -1
     DECLARE @WorkingNullRouteIP     varchar(50)

    SET @WorkingNullRouteIP = @a_NullRouteIP

    WHILE ( CHARINDEX('.',@WorkingNullRouteIP, @lastOctet ) > 0 )
      BEGIN
         SET @lastOctet = CHARINDEX('.',@WorkingNullRouteIP, @lastOctet )
         SET @octetCount = @octetCount + 1

         If @octetCount = 1
            BEGIN
              SET @firstOctet = CAST( SUBSTRING( @WorkingNullRouteIP, 1, @lastOctet - 1 ) )
            END

         If @octetCount = 2
           BEGIN
            SET @secondOctet = CAST( SUBSTRING( @WorkingNullRouteIP, 1, @lastOctet - 1 ) )
           END

         If @octetCount = 3
           BEGIN
            SET @thirdOctet = CAST( SUBSTRING( @WorkingNullRouteIP, 1, @lastOctet - 1 ) )   
           END                                 

         SET @WorkingNullRouteIP = SUBSTRING(@WorkingNullRouteIP, @lastOctet + 1)
         SET @lastOctet = 1
        END     

    -- Converting to this:    

    WHILE ( CHARINDEX('.',@WorkingNullRouteIP, @lastOctet ) > 0 )
     BEGIN
        SET @lastOctet = CHARINDEX('.',@WorkingNullRouteIP, @lastOctet )
        SET @octetCount = @octetCount + 1

        SELECT CASE @octetCount   
             WHEN 1 THEN 
                  SET @firstOctet = CAST( SUBSTRING( @WorkingNullRouteIP, 1, @lastOctet - 1 ) )
             WHEN 2 THEN 
                  SET @secondOctet = CAST( SUBSTRING( @WorkingNullRouteIP, 1, @lastOctet - 1 ) )
             WHEN 3 THEN 
                  SET @thirdOctet = CAST( SUBSTRING( @WorkingNullRouteIP, 1, @lastOctet - 1 ) )                                        
        END

        SET @WorkingNullRouteIP = SUBSTRING(@WorkingNullRouteIP, @lastOctet + 1)
        SET @lastOctet = 1
     END
```

Comment: This looks like you are trying to break an IP address into the 4 octets? Have you looked at PARSENAME?

Comment: A case statement can only return a value, it can't direct control of flow, so it can't contain commands like SET.

Comment: @TabAlleman: To clarify - the CASE *statement* is really a CASE *expression*, with the corresponding limitations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use the [PARSENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) function as described [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/PARSENAME/106755/)

```
DECLARE @WorkingNullRouteIP     varchar(50) = '192.168.100.1';
DECLARE @firstOctet             int = PARSENAME(@WorkingNullRouteIP,4),
        @secondOctet            int = PARSENAME(@WorkingNullRouteIP,3),
        @thirdOctet             int = PARSENAME(@WorkingNullRouteIP,2),
        @fourthOctet            int = PARSENAME(@WorkingNullRouteIP,1);

select 
     @firstOctet
    ,@secondOctet
    ,@thirdOctet
    ,@fourthOctet;
```

to give

```
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
192         168         100         1
```